# tput bel on linux ssh server

Tags: linux, ssh, audio

Suppose I'm connected to a computer A (ssh-server), via ssh through a computer B (ssh-client).

When I run the command "tput bel",
how to make the noise on the computer A
instead of making it, as default,on the computer B ?

Comment: paste the command you use please

Comment: ssh hostname ; - tput bel;

Comment: `tput bel` outputs the bell character defined for `$TERM`, which is *usually* `\a`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sudo -s 'tput bel >/dev/console'
```

is the best you're likely to do, I think.  (I can't test it properly here.)

Comment: And there is no way to do that without being root ?

Comment: `/dev/console` usually prohibits non-`root` from accessing `/dev/console`.  `/dev/tty1`, the first virtual console, can also be written to by *group* `root` by default.  Someone would have to change those permissions, which might require hacking whatever passes for `getty` in the case of `tty1`.  There's also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447166/how-to-use-pc-speaker-in-linux (probably same permissions issues).